# unusual struct definition in C

Tags: c, struct

I am looking at some code that has this kind of struct definition in it. At first, I thought it was a special way of defining a struct that defined it and instantiated one at the same time. However, my predictions about how this type of code behaves were wrong after I tested some similar code myself. Can someone tell me what this code does/where I could look online to see a description of this kind of code?

```
struct Error e = { .code = 22,
                   .msg = 22100 };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a struct definition, it's a designated initializer.  It's setting the `code` field to `22` and the `msg` field to `22100`.  Logically, you could rewrite it something like:

```
struct Error e = {0};
e.code = 22;
e.msg = 22100;
```

You can do something similar with arrays:

```
int a[5] = {
  [3] = 12,
  [4] = 17
};
```

Comment: Wow, your array example might come in handy.

Comment: GCC extends it further to be able to do ranges, too.

Comment: @CarlNorum Please add that in your answer

Comment: @VoidPointer, it's nonstandard, so I'm not sure that's appropriate.  You can read about it in the [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits).

Answer (score 4):

It's a C99 *designation initializer*.

Designation initializers allow you to initialize aggregate members in any order and they also allow you to omit members. Members that are not designated explicitly are initialized to `0`.

For example, `a` initialization here:

```
struct bla {int x; int y; int z;};
struct bla a = {.x =1, .z = 1};
```

is equivalent to C89 initialization below:

```
struct bla a = {1, 0, 1};
```

A note on terminology, it's a *designation initializer* and not a *designated initializer*. See defect report [DR#253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_253.htm):

> "The tem "designated initializer" is never mentioned in the Standard though it appears in the index and new features section (the Standard uses the term "designation initializer" in the text).

Comment: That DR is incorrect. The phrase "designation initializer" does not appear in the standard. A *designation* can be part of an *initializer*. And since the phrase "designated initializer" *does* appear in the index and in the new features section, I'd say that's the correct term.

Comment: @KeithThompson *designation* is present in a lot of places in the Standard: for example *(C11, 6.5.2.5p10) EXAMPLE 3 Initializers with designations*, or *(6.7.9p7) "When no designations are present"*. Also syntax in 6.7.9 uses *designation_opt initializer*.

Comment: Yes, but the phrase "designation initializer" is not used, and in particular is not used to refer to what most of us call a "designated initializer". The syntax in 6.7.9 doesn't use it as a phrase; it's simply an optional *designation* followed by an *initializer*.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a designated initializer, it's initializing an instance of the struct.

[Here’s GCC’s manual page about how to use them](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits).